# Read SQL Server query for ADODB.Connection from external file or from variable

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection-string

I have this Excel VBA code:

```vb
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim query As String

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx,xxxx;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=mydb;" & _
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute("")

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ...
End Sub
```

all works fine.

The issue is in this section: `Set rs = conn.Execute("")`

My select statement query is just too big, split it into continuation lines is not practical.

Is there a way of reading the query text from a file, or from a variable?

Thank you very much

Comment: You already have a variable declared for it `Dim query as String` once you populate it just `Set rs = conn.Execute(query)`  or maybe just make a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim query As String

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx,xxxx;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=mydb;" & _
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString

    'read SQL from file
    query = GetContent("C:\Stuff\myQuery.txt")

    Set rs = conn.Execute(query)

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ...
End Sub


'read all file content
Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 1).readall()
End Function
```

Alternatively, store your SQL in a worksheet cell and read it from there.

Comment: I tried this but it returned: End Sub expected when I rut it. Please help.

Comment: You can't run what I posted - you need to edit your existing code to work it in...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use continuation lines, you can append the strings and append a vbCrLf character.  e.g.

```
Dim sSQL as string
sSQL = "SELECT" & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & "AField" & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & ",BField" & vbCrLf
sSQL = sSQL & ",(SELECT XField FROM AnotherTable ..........) as XField" & vbCrlf
'and so on and so on
Set rs = conn.Execute(sSQL)
```

You can build very long SQL statements this way.